# named function does not resolve or reject promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

When i move promise's resolve/reject handling to a named function it does not work. Can someone explain why please?

works:

```
function getPremium(policyNumber, agentNumber) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        soap.createClient(wsdl, function (error, client) {
            client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader());
            client[config.webMethodName](soapBody(number), (error, soapResponse) => {
                return resolve(soapResponse);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

doesn't work:

```
var handleResponse = (error, soapResponse) => {
    return resolve(soapResponse);
}

function getPremium(policyNumber, agentNumber) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        soap.createClient(wsdl, function (error, client) {
            client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader());
            client[config.webMethodName](soapBody(number), handleResponse);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Of course it won't work, in this code `var handleResponse = (error, soapResponse) => { return resolve(soapResponse); }` is not defined. When `handleResponse` is created (parsed and interpreted) it binds to outside context (closure). `handleResponse` doesn't know how it is going to be used in future.

Comment: @dfsq - so there is no way of abstracting the callback out of the parent function for unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing along the `resolve` and `reject` functions, thus, `resolve(soapResponse);` will not work.

Add those to the parameter list and pass them to the `handleResponse` function.

Here's an example using currying:

```
var handleResponse = (resolve, reject) => (error, soapResponse) => { ... }
client[config.webMethodName](soapBody(number), handleResponse(resolve, reject));
```

Comment: love it! worked perfect. currying is my new favorite thing.

Comment: Just a side note, if you were not using arrow functions instead of currying you could've used `bind`. I suggest you check that too if you didn't already. It's one of the most important concepts one should know in javascript.